# Opencv MPEG7 descriptors

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, mpeg

I am working on the system that compares images. MPEG-7 standard provides some descriptors which can be used for that e.g: Dominant Color, Color Layout, Edge Histogramm, Color Coherence Vectors.
Do you know where i can get a source code for some of these methods?

Thx!

Comment: Do you need source code for a particular algorithm for calculating edge histogram etc., or will any method do? Also, you might consider adding the "image-processing" tag to your question. It may help other people to find your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the Windows and Linux executables, or easy-to-use API based on OpenCV library, developed for BilVideo-7 video indexing and retrieval system: http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~bilmdg/bilvideo-7/Software.html.

Answer (score 3):

The ISO distributes [reference software](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c035364_ISO_IEC_15938-6%28E%29_Reference_Software.zip) as part of the MPEG-7 standard, and among other things it includes feature extraction code for the visual descriptors.  The zip file contains another zip file called XMWin.zip, which contains the source.  (Despite the "Win" name, it contains instructions for compiling on both windows and unix.)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps to other programmers:

- [Here](http://chatzichristofis.info/?page_id=19) you can find one implementation on **C#**
- [Here](http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/) another implementation in **Java**.

Answer (score 1):

For Future readers, there's a CPP library that claims to be easy to use here. 
https://github.com/mubastan/mpeg7fex

This has been tested on OpenCV 3, so this is at par the latest.